# PCOMM gettext is pulling invisible information

Tags: vb.net

I've had a randomly recurring issue where I can use gettext to pull information just fine from a page on a PCOMM (IBM Personal Communicator) screen, then when I go to the next screen it will pull that SAME information, despite appearing visually blank.

I can't paste screenshots for InfoSec reasons...  But here's the gist:

```
Dim ps As New AutPS
Dim oia As New AutOIA
```

Page 1: ps.GetText(15,31,7) = 1800.00 (I can see this value on the screen.)

Go to next page, wait for oia.InputInhibited = 0 And ps.Ready

Page 2: ps.GetText(15,31,7) = 1800.00 (Screen in this position appears blank.)

This issue is not isolated, and is repeatable with a specific account number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution!

The key lies with using the ps.autECLFieldList. This object can detect when a given field (located using FindFieldByRowCol) is displayed or not, so when used in tandem with our getText, we can make sure that we're only retrieving information from a visible field.

```
Dim fl As Object = ps.autECLFieldList

fl.refresh() 'Good practice to make sure the Field List is up to date

If fl.FindFieldByRowCol(15, 31).display Then
   Amount = ps.GetText(15, 31, 7)
End If
```